# How to convert combination of char, number to integer in PHP

Tags: php

Actually my problem is,

Am performing dependent drop down, in that if i select a company it should show the list of `employee_id` which are belongs to selected `company`.

after that if i select a `employee_id` it must to show the `names` which is belongs to particular `employee_id`

```
id  company ID  Employee ID Name        Relationship    Dob     Age Gender       
1   EMPL        00001       Choodamani  Spouse      11-Aug-66   49  Female            
2   EMPL        00001       Komala      Mother      30-Oct-39   76  Female            
3   EMPL        00001       Varshini    Daughter    29-Apr-04   11  Female            
4   EMPL        00001       Vasudevan   Employee    15-Jul-62   53  Male    
5   EMPL        00002       Siddharth   Son         1-Jun-00    15  Male              
6   EMPL        00002       Poongavanam Mother      21-Oct-39   76  Female            
7   EMPL        00002       Aruna       Spouse      16-Sep-68   47  Female            
8   EMPL        00002       Abirami     Daughter    7-May-97    18  Female            
9   EMPL        00002       Murali      Employee    7-Oct-67    48  Male 
10   EMPL       E0003       Kalai       Employee    9-Nov-87    24  Male
11   EMPL       E0003       Devi        Wife        13-Nov-90   22  Male
```

so to group all the name which belongs to the employee_id, i have been using this code

```
$countClaimprocess = Employee::find()
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->count();

        $claimprocess1 = Employee::find()
                ->select('employee_id')
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->one();

        $claimprocess2 = Employee::find()
                ->select('importcompany_id')
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->one();

        $claim2 = $claimprocess2->importcompany_id;

        $claim = $claimprocess1->employee_id;

        $claimprocess = Employee::find()
                ->where("employee_id = $claim  and importcompany_id = $claim2")
                ->andwhere(" status != 'Deleted' ")
                ->all();

        if($countClaimprocess >= 0)
        {
            foreach($claimprocess as $claim)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$claim->id."'>".$claim->name."</option>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }

    }
```

But here, if i select a employee_id as interger its working perfectly example `00001`, `00002`. and showing the dependent name.
But if i select the employee_id like `E0002` or `E0003` , it not showing the dependent names

so what i need is how to convert combination of char, interger `(E0002)` into interger

Comment: HINT: Problem is on select('employee_id'), here this code only getting integer alone